# Implementing Charts.js in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, charts, laravel-5, chart.js

Hi I've been wondering around the net getting answers can't find one. I'm trying to display Chart using Charts.js..

In my route:

```
Route::get('surveys/chart', 'AboutController@projectChartData');
```

In my AboutController: I used *json_encode()* to pass data to my view

```
public function projectChartData()
    {
        $devlist = json_encode(DB::table('surveys')
            ->select(DB::raw('MONTHNAME(updated_at) as month'), DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(updated_at,'%Y-%m') as monthNum"),
                DB::raw('count(*) as projects'))
            ->groupBy('monthNum')
            ->get());

        return view('pages.chart',compact('devlist'));
    }
```

In my view:

```
<canvas id="projects-graph" width="1000" height="400"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $.getJSON("surveys/chart", function (result) {
            alert('');
            var labels = [],data=[];
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                labels.push(result[i].batch);
                data.push(result[i].created_at);
            }

            var buyerData = {
                labels : labels,
                datasets : [
                    {
                        fillColor : "rgba(240, 127, 110, 0.3)",
                        strokeColor : "#f56954",
                        pointColor : "#A62121",
                        pointStrokeColor : "#741F1F",
                        data : data
                    }
                ]
            };
            var buyers = document.getElementById('projects-graph').getContext('2d');
            new Chart(buyers).Line(buyerData, {
                bezierCurve : true
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

The problem It doesn't Display the Graph. But if I just return the data not using json_encode it gives me array() but charts.js needs json.

I'm really having difficulty implementing charts (morris,lavacharts,highcharts,charts.js) in laravel 5 since, not much of a proper turorial out of google. And if anyone can give me nice package I could use. big thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You will pass your data to view and in your view you will just **json_encode** like this `{!! json_encode($devlist) !!}`

Comment: I know I can also do that, but how do I put it inside the jquery in charts.js?

Comment: @never if you are initializing **chart.js** in your php file then it's simple put the blade echo in your js code. But if you are using separate js files for initializing then you have to declare an object and init with `{!! json_encode($devlist) !!}` and then use the object

Comment: can you demonstrate that one using the above code in my view?